# How to better realise include?

Tags: php

I currently have 3 files, 1 return array, 2 is command file that manipulate all other and 3 is function file,i include array and function file in command file. How to make array visible in function file, should i use second include or there another way?

file 1

```
return $arr = array(...);
```

file 2

```
function FuncName(){ $arr[1] = '1111';}
```

file 3

```
include_once 'file 1';
include_once 'file 2';
$arr[2] = '2222'
```

Comment: your code sample please ...

Comment: use require_once instead of include. so you wont include the files multiple times. use require_once in every file where you require other files (makes sense, right?). i would still suggest that you learn OOP.

Comment: @x4rf41 i use include_once, its same, differents between include and require its only in error and besides your advise is bad, its a bad practice to use require in every file, rather than one.I already use oop, just in this particular case i need to pass reference without making class for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. You can use [return](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) inside included file.

```
//main.php
include_once 'functions.php';
$array = include 'array.php';
goGoArray($array);

// functions.php
function goGoArray($array){
    var_dump($array);
}

// array.php
return array(1,23,456,7890);
```

But, if you what [global](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), use global.

```
//main.php
include_once 'functions.php';
$array = include 'array.php';
goGoArray();

// functions.php
function goGoArray(){
    global $array;
    var_dump($array);
}

// array.php
return array(1,23,456,7890);
```

P.S. But globals are very, very bad.

Comment: I tried require but it didnt worked, i think passsing variable is onlt way, thanks.

Comment: Could you provide your error message and code that not working?

Comment: its fine, im gonna pass variable.